# Multiplying and then summing values from two dictionaries (prices, stock)

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to multiply the values from each key and then add all the values together to print a single number. I know this probably super simple but i'm stuck

In my mind, I'd address this with something like:

```
for v in prices:
total = sum(v * (v in stock))
print total
```

But something like that isn't going to work :)

```
prices = {
"banana": 4,
"apple": 2,
"orange": 1.5,
"pear": 3 }

stock = {
"banana": 6,
"apple": 0,
"orange": 32,
"pear": 15 }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use a dict comprehension if you wanted the individuals:

```
>>> {k: prices[k]*stock[k] for k in prices}
{'orange': 48.0, 'pear': 45, 'banana': 24, 'apple': 0}
```

Or go straight to the total:

```
>>> sum(prices[k]*stock[k] for k in prices)
117.0
```

Comment: Assuming that `stock` has the same keys as `prices`.  Maybe `stock.get(k,1)` would be more appropriate, but I'm not sure ... Of if you're only interested in the overlap, on python3, `for k in prices.keys() & stock.keys()` (python2.7 it's keysview I think)

Comment: Yeah, depends on the use case.  I thought maybe `stock.get(k, 0)`, assuming that the default number to have was zero, but at least this way you get a nice `KeyError` and can decide from there. :^)

Comment: Oh, right.  `get(k,0)` would make more sense than using 1.  After all, you can't charge for an item you don't have in stock.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. I have been fine with one dictionary but working between two was difficult. Was trying to create a function and was obviously messing up there. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

If you would have known, how to iterate through a dictionary, index a dictionary using key and comprehend a dictionary, it would be a straight forward

```
>>> total = {key: price * stock[key] for key, price in prices.items()}
>>> total
{'orange': 48.0, 'pear': 45, 'banana': 24, 'apple': 0}
```

Even if your implementation of Python does not provide Dictionary comprehension (< Py 2.7), you can pass it as a List Comprehension to the `dict` built-in

```
>>> dict((key, price * stock[key]) for key, price in prices.items())
{'orange': 48.0, 'pear': 45, 'banana': 24, 'apple': 0}
```

If you don;t want compatible between 2.X and 3.X you can also use iteritems instead of 
items

```
{key: price * stock[key] for key, price in prices.iteritems()}
```

If you want a single total of the result, you can pass the individual products to `sum`

```
>>> sum(price * stock[key] for key, price in prices.items())
117.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct answer for codeacademy according to task description:

```
 prices = {
       "banana" : 4,
       "apple"  : 2,
       "orange" : 1.5,
       "pear"   : 3,
   }
   stock = {
        "banana" : 6,
        "apple"  : 0,
        "orange" : 32,
        "pear"   : 15,
    }

    for key in prices:
        print key
        print "price: %s" % prices[key]
        print "stock: %s" % stock[key]

     total = 0
     for key in prices:
        value = prices[key] * stock[key]
        print value
        total = total + value
    print total
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're on codeacademy? If so just do this:

```
total = 0
for key in prices:  
    prices = 53
    stock = 10.5
    total = prices + stock
print total
```

Unlike what the instructions said you would have to add all the values together before multiplying them and adding them to total. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I  wrote the following code and it worked.
for key in prices:

```
print key
   print "price: %s" % + prices[key]
   print "stock: %s" % + stock[key]
```

for key in prices:
    value = prices[key]*stock[key]
    print value
    total = total + value
    print total

Comment: Welcome to SO :) It's always better to add an explanation to the code you're posting as an answer, so that it will helps visitors understand why this is a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and general answer.

If you are looking for an efficient and fast way to **multiply** the elements (values) of two dictionaries together, do use **dict comprehension**.
Be sure the two dictionaries have the same keys.
You could use this one-liner:

```
new_dict = { key : value * dict2[key] for key,value in dict1.items() }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
total = 0   
for key in prices:
    print prices[key] * stock[key]
    total += prices[key] * stock[key]
print total
```