# How to print 4 lists vertically next to each other, my second list has trailing newlines

Tags: python-3.x, string-formatting, shopping-cart, output-formatting

I have four lists called `items2` ( quantity) , `items` ( the codes) , `newprice_list` (final price) and `product_list` (the name of the products). I tried to print them side-by-side like this:

```
123213  banana   4   £5
```

I tried this...

```
All_list=[items , product_list , newprice_list , items2]
for a in zip(*All_list):
    print(*a)
```

...however it gave me this output:

```
86947367 banana
 10 2
```

The thing is , when I print out the lists `newprice_list` and `items2` they do not have the " quotes like the other two lists , which I think is the problem, however I do not know how to solve it. I have turned `items2` and items into integers.

EDIT: When I rearrange the order it works, however I need it to be in that order.

Comment: anyone , has an alternative method ?

Comment: Your items list is terminated with newline characters.

Comment: Vaguely related questions on shopping-cart calculations: [Multiplying and then summing values from two dictionaries (prices, stock)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087118/multiplying-and-then-summing-values-from-two-dictionaries-prices-stock). And take a browse of the [tag:shopping-cart] tag.

Comment: Your items list seems to be terminated with newlines, so clean it up by running `items = [i.strip() for i in items]`. See [**How do I trim whitespace?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185524/how-do-i-trim-whitespace/1185529#1185529) or [Remove all whitespace in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270092/remove-all-whitespace-in-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I trim whitespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185524/how-do-i-trim-whitespace)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `print(*a)`, which is changed to `print("382918", "banana", ...)`, try printing the array a seperating it by spaces:

```
print(' '.join(list(map(str, a))))
```

1. Map applies "str" to each element in a
2. list changes the type to list (return value is list of strings)
3. `' '.join(..)` generates string where values in list (generated by `list(map(...))`) are joine by space.

If you have `\n` that triggers new line somewhere, you can strip it in the same one-liner:

```
print(' '.join(list(map(lambda x: strip(str(x)), a))))
```

Lambda is anonimous function that will be applied to each element of a. It turns it to string (not changes if already string) and strips all the `\n`s

Comment: If you're immediately consuming the `map` you don't need to wrap it in a `list`; `' '.join(map(str, a))` is fine, and avoids creating an unnecessary intermediate list. Also, I'd recommend using a comprehension instead of a lambda expression in a map: `' '.join(str(x).strip() for x in a)`