# Is there a way to divide with each other the corresponding values of two dictionaries with matching keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following two dictionaries:

```
dict1={'Hewey': 4, 'Dewey': 24, 'Louie': 15, 'Donald': 56, 'Scrooge': 9}

dict2={'Hewey': 2, 'Dewey': 6, 'Louie': 3, 'Donald': 2, 'Scrooge': 3}
```

Is there a way to divide the elements of `dict1` by the corresponding elements of `dict2`, such that I get the following result in dictionary form?

```
dict3={'Hewey': 2, 'Dewey': 4, 'Louie': 5, 'Donald': 28, 'Scrooge': 3}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiplying and then summing values from two dictionaries (prices, stock)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087118/multiplying-and-then-summing-values-from-two-dictionaries-prices-stock)

Comment: Another one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334783/multiplying-values-from-two-different-dictionaries-together-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

If your keys always overlap, then this is enough:

```
dict3 = {k: (dict1[k] / dict2[k]) for k in dict1}
```